# Identity - Showing GUID instead names

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can someone help and tell me why these 4 users below ( inside the red circle ) showing the GUID not their names under the identity when I look them in group lookup How do I fix it? The 4 users were recently added and they were created in local Active Directory same way with the others.
Sorry for my english but hopefully you guys will understand me. Thank you so much

```
$DDLName = "Gold Coast"
$DDLProperties = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $DDLName
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter ($DDLProperties.RecipientFilter)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/snRP9.png]

Comment: Are you generating this list using script?

Comment: @Faisal yes sir

Comment: could you please edit the question and  include what script are you using?

Comment: @Icebear can you please provide your script and if you are not comfortable sharing that then provide the command which gets the data for the Identity column.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

```
$DDLName = "DDLNAME"
$DDLProperties = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $DDLName
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter ($DDLProperties.RecipientFilter)
```

[image]

> **Note**  that: Microsoft updated the naming scheme for the user's Name parameter, being displayed as externaldirectoryobjectid. Refer this  [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/change-in-naming-convention-of-user-s-name-parameter/bc-p/3300407?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002496)

To resolve the GUID to Name, you can make use of parameters like  `DisplayName`  or  `Name`.

```
(Get-Recipient 860047a6-a9bc-4d63-8d6f-XXXX).DisplayName
```

[image]

If still the issue persists, check whether users are active and have Office 365 license.

**Reference:**

[Changes in Exchange Mailbox Names and Distinguished Names by Tony Redmond](https://office365itpros.com/2022/04/21/exchange-online-distinguished-names/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total Powershell novice, I just use it to pry out bits and pieces. I also ran into this problem, GUID's appearing at the end by surprise. I spotted the secondary-query copy/paste solution, but a little random stabbing in the dark created this query that ran, and successfully too.

```
$DDG = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity “Lansing”
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter ($DDG.RecipientFilter) | Select DisplayName
```

It worked a charm. Hope this helps folks...